# How to implement TADSevent like functionality for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, delphi, advantage-database-server

I'm using Delphi 10.3 and Advantage DataBase. 
Here, I have used `sp_SignalEvent` method and then, used the `TADSEvent` which get triggered for all the ADS connected application and handled the operation based on the requests.

Is there any similar operation is present in SQL Server.?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has Query Notifications:

> Built upon the Service Broker infrastructure, query notifications
>   allow applications to be notified when data has changed. This feature
>   is particularly useful for applications that provide a cache of
>   information from a database, such as a Web application, and need to be
>   notified when the source data is changed.

- [Query Notifications in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server)
- [Working with Query Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/working-with-query-notifications?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Detecting Changes with SqlDependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency)